# Pre-image of a dense subspace is dense

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T : H\rightarrow H$ be a continuous, injective, symmetric operator on a real Hilbert space $H$. Let $V$ be a subspace of $H$ such that $T(V)$ is dense in $H$. Must $V$ be dense in $H$?

Comment: The example you accepted is neither injective nor symmetric.